# JQuery add <td> to table for inconsistent rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML table with an inconsistent number of  tags per row. For example, one row might have 5  tags and another row might have 2  tags. Is there a convenient way to "pad" the rows with  tags containing "N/A" so that there are a consistent number of tags per row?

Quick example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to add  tags to all rows that contain less than 5  tags.

Comment: can use `colspan` , otherwise provide sample input and expected output. There are numerous ways rows might need to be padded

Comment: @charlietfl see my example.

Comment: What's generating this mismatched code, can that not be fixed? And where should the padding cells be added, at the beginning, at the end, in the middle..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method of doing it. First, loop through each row and count how many td elements it has in it. Keep track of the highest number.

```
var mostTDs = 0;
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var thisTDs = $(this).find('td').length;
    if(thisTDs > mostTDs)
        mostTDs = thisTDs;
});
```

Then, loop through again and say this time that if the number of tds in this row is less than the largest number, loop and add a td for each extra cell to be added.

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
    var thisTDs = $(this).find('td').length;
    for(i = thisTDs; i < mostTDs; i++) {
        $('<td/>').html('x').appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

[**Here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7b1y2349/1/)

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for; my javascript/jquery is very limited but this makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. As the comments have suggested, this kind of scenario is often best fixed at the root of the problem rather than the client side, but it's still good for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns you need is 'max' then you can try below jquery snippet.

Check each tr and count its child elements . Add td if the total td are less than 'max', then add td.

```
var max=5;

$('tr').each(function() {
var count = $(this).children().length;
For (int i=count; i <max:i++){
$(this).append("<td>NA</td>");
}
});
```

If you don't know the value of 'max' then first run a each function to find the max td value.
    Var Max=0;
    $('tr').each(function() {
    var count =     $(this).children().length;
    if (count> max){
    Max=count;
    }
    });

Comment: Remove the quotes around "this"